# Pino - "unable to determine transport target for..." - When adding library from github

Tags: node.js, package.json, pinojs

I tried to fork a simple pino transport "pino-loki" on github and wan't to add it as my dependency.
package.json seems to be fine and the library is pulled from github.

```
"pino-loki": "mygithub/pino-loki"
```

But for some reason pino can't initialise this transporter.

```
{
    target: 'pino-loki',
    level:"info",
    options: {
        host: 'http://localhost:3100',
        batching: true,
        interval: 5,
    }
},
```

> Error: unable to determine transport target for "pino-loki"

I can see it in my node_modules, are there any additional steps I'm missing?

Comment: having the same issue here...

Comment: Sorry. I don't remember how and or if I fixed this

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with `pino-mongodb` and SvelteKit. It worked ok in dev, but I had the same "unable to determine transport target for" error once it was deployed to Vercel.

My solution was to add the following line at the top of the file where I'm initialising the logger:

```
import 'pino-mongodb';
```

See a similar SO post here [pino-datadog-transport with Next.js on Vercel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73460660/pino-datadog-transport-with-next-js-on-vercel)